Can a single DTC conatin Snapshot records with different DIDs?
Suppose I have configured DID_1, DID_2 DID_3 and DID_4. If I have assigned 2 snapshot records for a DTC(0x610091), can I have DID_1 and DID_2 for snapshot record 1 and DID_3 and DID_4 for snapshot record 2?
I am getting no clue to assign different DIDs to different Snapshot Records of a DTC as DemFreezeFrameClass has DemDidClassRef which can be configured per DTC.

I assume your question relates to Service ReadDTCInformation (0x19) sub-function reportDTCSnapshotRecordByDTCNumber (0x04):
 and whether the same dataIdentifiers (DIDs) must be part of each DTCSnapshotRecord for each DTC.
According to ISO 14229-1:

Comment

It is not directly stated by ISO standard that each DTC Snapshot must contain the same DIDs within one server (ECU).
The description suggests that data-parameters shall reflect vehicle conditions at the time of the failure occurrence (DTC reporting).

Conclusions
It is not forbidden, therefore it is allowed to use different DIDs in DTCSnapshotRecords for various DTC. I would say that it is recommended way as the provided data-parameters shall reflect information that might help with diagnosing the problem (each DTC has different symptom therefore different data-parameters would be needed to provide detailed information about those).
Comment
Content of each DTCSnapshotRecord is defined by OEM (Vehicle Manufacturer) or system provided. As a user, you can only read these information. So I assume you are either a developer or a system engineer within a project that implements reportDTCSnapshotRecordByDTCNumber sub-function.
PS. I am not sure if I understood your question correctly as it is not very precise, so please correctly me if I misunderstood something.

I have created UDS knowledge base: https://uds.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/knowledge_base.html
In the future, this and similar information would be part of the documentation.

Use of "DEM" hints that this is a question for which the limitations (or extensions) of a specific AUTOSAR vendor may need to be considered!

AUTOSAR is in line with ISO 14229-1, so the answer is still valid. There is no code in the question, so I am not providing one. If OP provides one, then I can help to fix it.
